# Setting error message from Sitecore when using MVC form

Tags: sitecore-client, mvc-forms

I am using MVC form in Sitecore.

In order to validate fields i am using attributes over model fields. My requirement is to get the error message from Sitecore instead of hardcoding it.

I am currently using Required,Regex,RequiredIf,Remote validation of MVC.

Can I achieve this?
The error messages are in an item inside different field names

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, just use constants and get copy from Sitecore dictionries. Habitat has a great example. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Models/LoginInfo.cs

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Attributes;
    using Sitecore.Foundation.Dictionary.Repositories;

    public class LoginInfo
    {
        [Display(Name = nameof(EmailCaption), ResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Required), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(InvalidEmailAddress), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = nameof(PasswordCaption), ResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Required), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [PasswordMinLength(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(MinimumPasswordLength), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LoginInfo))]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<FedAuthLoginButton> LoginButtons { get; set; }

        public static string EmailCaption => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Login/Email", "E-mail");
        public static string PasswordCaption => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Login/Password", "Password");
        public static string MinimumPasswordLength => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Login/Minimum Password Length", "Please enter a password with at lease {1} characters");
        public static string Required => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Login/Required", "Please enter a value for {0}");
        public static string InvalidEmailAddress => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Login/Invalid Email Address", "Please enter a valid email address");
    }
}
```

Comment: My error messages are clubbed in an item i.e inside different fields.

Comment: That is still fine, it just needs to be a static call.